# How to store Excel file in s3 using aws-sdk in node js?

Tags: node.js, excel, buffer, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

```
    var xls = json2xls(data);
    var bufferdata = new Buffer(xls).toString('base64');
    console.log("inside upload s3 function........", data);
    //var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
    var uploaddata = {
        Key: "exception.xls",
        Body: bufferdata,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    };
```

I am able to save and retrieve the file over s3. But Format mismatch is coming up. Please help me as how to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, worked for me.

```
const xls = json2xls(data);

const buffer = Buffer.from(xls, 'binary');

console.log("inside upload s3 function........", data);
var uploaddata = {
    Key: "exception.xls",
    Body: buffer,
    ContentType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sameer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6814428/sameer-narvekar) solution works perfect for xlsx/xls filetype.

For CSV. I used [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) package.

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
const fields = ['id', 'title', 'description'];
const opts = { fields };
const parser = new Parser(opts);
const csv = parser.parse(your data);

const uploaddata = {
Key: "exception.csv",
Body: csv,
ContentType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
};
```

Happy coding ;)